# Progress .gif not displaying for a .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write some code so that while the file pts.php is loaded into the #content div on index.php (on page load) a loading gif will be displayed, as pts.php is quite large and takes a few seconds. I don't want people to start spam clicking and refreshing trying to get it to work, hence the gif.

The problem I'm having is that the gif is not displaying at all as far as I can tell. Is there a way to test if it is showing, and if it isn't does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I've got the div #loadingimagepage hidden via CSS and this code is in the  of the index.php page with script tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadingimagepage').show();
    $("#content"). load ("pts.php");
    $('#loadingimagepage').hide();
```

This is then the #content div:

```
<div id="content">
        <div id="loadingimagepage">
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help/tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add the hide in the callback of `load`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will process without waiting for the load to finish.  You need to put the `$('#loadingimagepage').hide();` in your completion of the load function.

Ex

```
$("#content").load("pts.php", function(){
    $('#loadingimagepage').hide();
});
```

You can even test if your load was successful and notify the user if it wasn't (while still hiding the loading gif)

```
$("#content").load("pts.php", function(passedSuccessVar){
    $('#loadingimagepage').hide();
    if(!passedSuccessVar) { alert("Error!Error! Danger Will Robinson");}
});
```

What you currently have:

```
$('#loadingimagepage').show();   //starts showing right away
$("#content"). load ("pts.php"); //starting loading content
$('#loadingimagepage').hide();   //hides the loading gif regardless of the previous function status
```

Comment: @user2547576 Glad I could help, please mark as correct if this was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`load` is asynchronous so you need to wait for it to finish.

You need something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loadingimagepage').show();
    $("#content").load("pts.php", function(){
        $('#loadingimagepage').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` functions to show or hide the loading image.

Whenever an Ajax request is about to be sent, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none are in progress, jQuery triggers the ajaxStart event. Any and all handlers that have been registered with the `.ajaxStart()` method are executed at this time.

```
  $('#loadingimagepage').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
       $(this).show();  
  }).ajaxStop (function(){
     $(this).hide(); 
  });
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/